# How do you detect pitch using an FFT transformed array?

Tags: java, real-time, fft, microphone, pitch-tracking

So I have an array of transformed complex numbers. I do not know what do with the returned data. I've tried calculating the magnitude each element, designating  the one with the highest element as the correct frequency, but found that I get weird numbers like 5,000hz often. Is there a better operation I can perform on the returned data to determine pitch?

Note: I want to use the pitch as part of Voice Activity Detection Algorithm.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about (applied) mathemathics

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about DSP and belongs on http://DSP.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different algorithms for pitch detection - I recommend you try using the [Harmonic Product Spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm) method, since you have already embarked down the FFT-based route, and it's fairly simple to implement one you have a power spectrum.